# Calculation using a sqlite db in python

Tags: python, database, loops, sqlite

i've generated a database file running sqlite3 inside a python script. now i'm trying to make some calculation with the data inside the db but i'm having trouble running a loop that get a name from a txt file to help in the data range selection. anyone can help me with this please or indicate what would be the best way to make calculations with the database data.

This is what i have in the text file and i want to use the name "Candy" and Cannon's Roar as a filter for the data selection
GPB, Candy, 14 4.333
GPB, Cannon's Roar, 5

and here is what i'm trying to run

```
import sqlite3
import re
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('raceinfo.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
base = open("base/dognames.txt").read()
nome = re.findall(re.compile('(.+?), (.+?), (.+?)'),base)

for n in name:
  cursor.execute("SELECT AVG(FINALPLACE) from BASEINICIAL WHERE name =('"+str(n[1]+"')")
  print cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

many thanks

Comment: What trouble are you having?

Comment: The select funtion doesnt work when i try the look using the ('"+str(n[1]+"')")

Comment: What do you mean with "doesnt work"?

Comment: it doesnt read the above as a valid syntax. this is the error that i get

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "upt.py", line 10
    print cursor.fetchone()[0]
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a closing parenthesis after `n[1]`:

```
cursor.execute("... WHERE name =('"+str(n[1])+"')")
```

To avoid formatting problems like this, and escaping problems when there is a name containing a quote, better use parameters:

```
cursor.execute("... WHERE name = ?", (n[1],))
```